# How do I access extra fields in a Laravel 5 pivot table?

Tags: laravel, model, pivot-table, laravel-5

I have two Laravel 5 models connected by a pivot table and belongsToMany relationships. As you can see below I have orders, items and the pivot table item_order.

Order:

```
public function items() {
    return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Item', 'item_order', 'order_id', 'item_id') -> withPivot('id','quantity');
}
```

Item:

```
public function orders() {
    return $this -> belongsToMany('App\Order', 'item_order', 'item_id', 'order_id') -> withPivot('id','quantity');
}
```

When looping through

```
$orders->items as $item
```

I can't seem to access the extra field 'quantity'. If I

```
dd($item)
```

I get:

```
Item {#310 ▼
  #table: "items"
  +timestamps: true
  #dates: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  #attributes: array:11 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2015-03-23 21:30:19"
    "updated_at" => "2015-03-25 15:37:23"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "name" => "Medium Lift Sling"
    "description" => "Green with orange details"
    "url" => "http://www.atlaslifttech.com/slings/patienthighback"
    "image" => "atlas-highback-sling.jpg"
    "manufacturer_id" => 1
    "itemtype_id" => 1
    "notes" => null
  ]
  #original: array:15 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2015-03-23 21:30:19"
    "updated_at" => "2015-03-25 15:37:23"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "name" => "Medium Lift Sling"
    "description" => "Green with orange details"
    "url" => "http://www.atlaslifttech.com/slings/patienthighback"
    "image" => "atlas-highback-sling.jpg"
    "manufacturer_id" => 1
    "itemtype_id" => 1
    "notes" => null
    "pivot_order_id" => 1
    "pivot_item_id" => 1
    "pivot_id" => 6
    "pivot_quantity" => 0
  ]
  #relations: array:2 [▶]
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  #forceDeleting: false
}
```

So the quantity is there under original but I've tried

```
{{ $item->quanity }} and {{ $item->pivot_quantity }}
```

and even

```
{{ $item->original['pivot_quantity'] }}
```

And nothing is ever output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You access the properties on the pivot property:

```
$item->pivot->quantity
```

---

**P.S.** In the future, instead of `dd`ing the model directly, convert it to an array first:

```
dd($item->toArray());
```

It'll be easier to see just the attributes and relations.